# Was Andrew still under the influence of the Cupid Bee?

Tags: little-witch-academia

In Episode 10 of *Little Witch Academia*, Andrew and several other characters are stung by a Cupid Bee, causing them to fall in love with the first person they see (in Andrew's case, Akko). This manifests as a visible blush on their cheeks and an uncontrollable infatuation. When first stung, Andrew confesses his love to Akko, kisses her hand, then [wall-slams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabedon) her and asks her to kiss him.

However, when Andrew catches up to Akko after she runs off, he is no longer blushing, nor does he act anywhere near as infatuated as he did initially. He spends most of the conversation with his back to Akko, acting as curt and disinterested as he usually does when around her, and while he does compliment her ("You know, you're pretty cute"), he says it in a more casual, off-hand manner than the breathless declarations of love he'd been making earlier.

Compared to how the other stung characters acted, and how he himself had been acting just a few minutes prior, the difference in behaviour is startling to me. Which leads me to wonder... **was Andrew still under the influence of the Cupid Bee at that point?**

- If so, then how come he was so much colder towards Akko than he was when first stung?
- If not, then how come his infatuation wore off so much quicker than everyone else's?